# Why doesn't type assertion get rid of "Element implicitly has an 'any' type" in this particular case?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror, tsc, typechecking

I have this code (it's a bit concocted, but I need it to be this way and with this type structure).
Basically I want an array to be sorted this way:

- first by the item type
- then by the owner
- then by the value

I.e. if there are two elements with the same itemType, then owner is considered and so on. This is just in case, it should not have any direct relation to the `tsc` error in question.

```
'use strict';

type Item = {
  itemType: 'itemTypeA' | 'itemTypeB';
  belongsTo: 'ownerA' | 'ownerB';
  value: number;
};

type Argument = {
  items: Item[];
};

const a: Argument = {
  items: [
    {
      itemType: 'itemTypeB',
      belongsTo: 'ownerA',
      value: 0,
    },
    {
      itemType: 'itemTypeA',
      belongsTo: 'ownerB',
      value: 1,
    },
    {
      itemType: 'itemTypeB',
      belongsTo: 'ownerA',
      value: 10,
    },
    {
      itemType: 'itemTypeB',
      belongsTo: 'ownerA',
      value: 0,
    },
  ],
};
console.log(testFunc(a));

function testFunc(arg: Argument): string {
  const sortByData = new Map([
    ['itemType', { itemTypeA: 0, itemTypeB: 1, },],
    ['belongsTo', { ownerA: 0, ownerB: 1, },],
    ['value', null,],
  ]);
  arg.items.sort((a, b) => {
    for (const [propName, sortValues] of sortByData) {
      //// @ts-ignore: failed to make it work with type checks
      const aValue = sortValues ? sortValues[a[propName]] as any as number : a[propName];
      ////// @ts-ignore: failed to make it work with type checks
      //const bValue = sortValues ? sortValues[b[propName]] : b[propName];
      //if (aValue > bValue) {
      //  return 1;
      //} else if (aValue < bValue) {
      //  return -1;
      //}
    }
    return 0;
  });
  console.log('AAA', arg.items);
  return '123';
}
```

The problem is that this line:

```
const aValue = sortValues ? sortValues[a[propName]] as any as number : a[propName];
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

causes this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any'
> can't be used to index type '{ itemTypeA: number; itemTypeB: number;
> ownerA?: never; ownerB?: never; } | { ownerA: number; ownerB: number;
> itemTypeA?: never; itemTypeB?: …

I know that this (the ~~ underlined) expression is a number. It'd suffice for me just to assert it's a number, but even this didn't work.

So could someone please explain, why the type assertion doesn't work in this case, or, more generally, **what is the best way to get rid of the error?** (The only one I've found is to just disable the type checking with `// @ts-ignore: failed to make it work with type checks`)

Comment: You need multiple assertions because you have multiple locations with errors.  You can do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/Wv1vrm) for example.  There is almost certainly away to refactor your code to require fewer or no assertions (I would completely abandon `Map` and just use a plain object for starters) but that's out of scope for the question as asked.  Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz thank you, this has helped. I just had to adjust the solution in the comment to my real situation, which code I may not post here. **Will you post that comment as an asnwer?** The more general problems are: how to deal with tsc errors (currently I think it's: read the messages carefully, also may try to look into the source code of `tsc`). And problem 2: **is it okay to have so many type assertions? What's the point? Wouldn't it be better just to disable type checking for such lines?**

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance. ... I would never recommend `//@ts-ignore` unless you've exhausted all other options.  All `//@ts-ignore` does is suppress the warning from being emitted; it doesn't fix them.  It's like putting opaque tape over a warning light on your car's dashboard.  If you're lucky, the suppressed warning won't affect other code in your code base; if you're unlucky, you will have weird problems elsewhere.  It's always better to resolve a warning than to suppress it.  I don't know how much of that belongs in an answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had multiple type errors in different locations, so you would need multiple [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to resolve them.  In something like `sortValues[a[propName]]`, you are relying on `propName` to be seen as a valid key of `a`, and `a[propName]` to be seen as a valid key of `sortValues`.  Neither of these are true for the code you've written. Going into why that's the case is out of scope here, but if you want to resolve via type assertion, you'll need to assert each one of those:

```
const aValue = sortValues ?
    sortValues[a[propName as keyof Item] as keyof typeof sortValues] as number :
    a[propName as keyof Item];
```

If you're just trying to resolve errors by turning off type checking you can reduce the number of assertions by making use of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any):

```
arg.items.sort((a: any, b) => {
    for (const [propName, sortValues] of sortByData as Map<string, any>) {
        const aValue = sortValues ? sortValues[a[propName]] : a[propName];
    }
    return 0;
});
```

You *can* use [the `//@ts-ignore` comment directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments) to suppress errors, but I would never recommend this unless you've exhausted all other options.  Doing so doesn't turn off type checking; it just disables *displaying* the error. And while an error might be displayed in some line of your code, the underlying problem might not be confined to that line... so you could potentially see strange problems in other places in your code.  In other words, compiler errors are often indicative of some actual problem, and that actual problem would still be there if you `//@ts-ignore` it.  For something as trivial as a type assertion there probably wouldn't be such non-local effects, but for something as trivial as a type assertion you should just use the type assertion in the first place.  As it says in the documentation, "we recommend you use these comments *very sparingly*."

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#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-EZKAAfHLiqyRKooGSFX5wmBVCIwAA5YzpD0FgBqSIgUkiwdZStrqo1WqZVZ6jagxn7-X8fYHUigAH4ESUV-0pOFjM3Wx2u9BjGuANYQEAiUdhBDDs9QS-X0euCA3scqxcWIfztfWWw1CgUgt2KA8WzbTt0j-J8rw-O9ol+e5VAgYAzFUMQUX0HAHEzLMczzAsi2SecxBAEsy2QSsAQMGs6wbBImwg49u0-YBv0HYcPwLNVNW1GCjTAAAeKUZQkD1jDI8syxoko5wXAdl3HDi13XNiVP3Q9IJPSJh3IcCjygiBELRZDUPQzCBmw7BcOsqAFQJYlSTJCg6Dcm1swkXMCCkTMDBQtCMMofYACYAGYeAwBwgA)